# Python regular expression to match a specific position of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using RegEx in python to match only 8 characters starting from the 7th one of each of the following strings :

> ```
> 158013158-S-0101
> 159013159-S-0102
> 155515234-S-0111
> 159013159-S-0101
> ```

For example : i want to match only the yellow part of this string :

> [image]

So please, can someone help me with this

Comment: Why do you use regex instead of string slicing? As in ``'159013159-S-0101'[6:14]``?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that i found, i used :

> `.*(.{8}).{2}`

**.{8}** : is for the number of characters that i want to capture.

**.{2}** : is for the position (2 = start at the 3rd one from the end)

.

[image]

.

This is the demo here :

https://regex101.com/r/WExayU/1/